# SQL Grouping by Year

Tags: sql

Using the [w3schools db](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_groupby), I have to create these queries. I am stuck on a couple questions and thought I'd ask..

Q2: Show top 5 employees, excluding the top employee (show employees ranked 2-5) in terms of total sales done by those employees. In the query display employee's first name, last name and TotalSales sorted in descending order. Filter the Data for only orders done in year 1996.

My code without the year filtering is:

```
SELECT e.LastName, e.FirstName, SUM(od.Quantity*p.Price) AS OrderTotal
FROM [Employees] AS e 
JOIN [Orders] AS o ON o.EmployeeID=e.EmployeeID
JOIN [OrderDetails] AS od ON od.OrderID=o.OrderID
JOIN [Products] AS p ON od.ProductID=p.ProductID
GROUP BY e.EmployeeID
ORDER BY OrderTotal DESC
LIMIT 4
OFFSET 1
```

I am not sure how to only return it with orders in 1996, when I try to Group By year 1996 doesn't seem to help..

Thank you!

Comment: What RDBMS are you supposed to be using?

Comment: @Lamak: The nonstandard square brackets rather than standard quotation marks spell "Microsoft SQL Server".

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' But the `LIMIT` doesn't

Comment: @Lamak, sorry I am very new to this. I am just using whatever is on w3schools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the WebSQL database used for w3schools doesn't seem to support year() I think you could use this instead:

```
SELECT e.LastName, e.FirstName, SUM(od.Quantity*p.Price) AS OrderTotal
FROM [Employees] AS e 
JOIN [Orders] AS o ON o.EmployeeID=e.EmployeeID
JOIN [OrderDetails] AS od ON od.OrderID=o.OrderID
JOIN [Products] AS p ON od.ProductID=p.ProductID
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN '1996-01-01' AND '1996-12-31'
GROUP BY e.EmployeeID
ORDER BY OrderTotal DESC
LIMIT 4
OFFSET 1
```

It seems to work when I tested with Chrome (but not Firefox)

Comment: I'm glad I wasn't the only one who couldn't use year() or datepart() on w3schools.

Comment: @McAdam331 Yeah, got the same error. Seems to be an issue with the db used.

Comment: Thank you, this worked great. I used WHERE as well, but I guess it's just the w3schools DB that doesn't support it. I wonder why

Answer (score 1):

You can use the YEAR() function. Check out this list of useful [datetime](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) functions.

Try this new query:

```
SELECT e.LastName, e.FirstName, SUM(od.Quantity*p.Price) AS OrderTotal
FROM [Employees] AS e 
JOIN [Orders] AS o ON o.EmployeeID=e.EmployeeID
JOIN [OrderDetails] AS od ON od.OrderID=o.OrderID
JOIN [Products] AS p ON od.ProductID=p.ProductID
WHERE YEAR([OrderDate]) = 1996
GROUP BY e.EmployeeID
ORDER BY OrderTotal DESC
LIMIT 4
OFFSET 1
```

Comment: "Syntax error in FROM clause." You might want to test your answer in the OP's database (linked in the question).

Comment: Well I'm beat trying to figure out why this is failing. It won't even let me use DATEPART(). Might be an issue with w3schools.

Comment: It appears that function isn't supported. You might want to test your suggestion with another database (not linked).

Comment: yea, this one doesn't seem to work with w3schools. Any idea why some snytax works and some don't? (Also, thank you VERY MUCH!)

Comment: @eri that would probably be a question for them. jpw has a good solution that worked with w3schools. In my experience with MySQL the year() function works fine. I would suggest, however, that you bookmark the datetime functions I linked to. I use that pretty regularly, it covers everything you may need for dates.

Comment: Anytime. Feel free to accept and upvote the answer if you think it's best.

Answer (score 0):

## CODE:

```
WHERE DATEPART(year, [OrderDate])=1996
```